# Multivariate numeric dataset for clustering

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I am searching for a multivariate dataset consisting of vectors (no time series) for clustering experiments. It should have about 8-20 numeric features (non-numeric would have to be ignored by me) and about 100-500 instances. Having some labels additionally might be useful, but is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with the **2011 Irish Census** dataset for clustering and demographic classification previously and found it to be very useful.

http://www.cso.ie/en/census/census2011smallareapopulationstatisticssaps/

There are various aggregated levels you can download the data, some of which are in your 100-500 instances range. There is also a fairly comprehensive data dictionary available.

There are no labels but mapping your results (boundary files are also available) would provide some sort of clarification (you wouldn't expect a cluster with high proportion of farmers to be in an urban area).

Comment: Thanks! Which algorithms did you use? I know how my algorithm works and I am pretty firm in clustering in general, so I should be able to predict whether my algorithm will work as well if you tell me. Also, do you have a specific set (a specific CSV) that you used, you know worked well for demonstration and you could upload?

Comment: I used k-means clustering after performing principal component analysis. As for a CSV of the specific data I used, I'm afraid this has been lost to time but I will try to root it out and update if I manage to do so